# Modifying Rails gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using tomichj/invitation for a project I'm doing, it has all the functionality I need, except it uses email. And there is no way to disable this email feature from it's config file.

How do I alter it so I can run the gem without it's email function, can I extend a gem's controller to bypass the email function entirely?

Comment: This explains pretty well.. https://github.com/tomichj/invitation/blob/master/README.md#controllers

Comment: You can fork the gem, install the gem locally or specify the path in the gemfile to be the path of the forked github repo
This was you can make any changes to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the gem's controller, yes. Another way to do it which would give you more control would be to fork the gem, alter it to remove the email function, and use your fork instead of the main gem. You'd have to pay attention to bugfixes in the trunk, but that shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to do that right now, I have forked the gem and downloaded, but how to I rename it and install it afterwards?

Comment: Depends on how you're using it. You may not need to rename it; you could just change your Gemfile (I'm assuming you're using Bundler) to use your git repository for the source instead of rubygems.org by putting `git: "https://github.com/youruser/forkedgem.git"` after the gem's name.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily open a gem by using the `gem open <gemname>` command.

So in your case, you can use `gem open invitation`. This will modify the installed gem directly. But be aware that updates will remove these modifications.

BTW if you want to use your preferred editor you can specify the `EDITOR` env variable.

E.g.: `EDITOR=subl gem open invitation`